# Can a recruiter release your reference name and number to their client

Tags: recruitment, clients

I was approached by a recruiter regarding a job. I sent my resume and had first interview with regional nurse. A second interview was scheduled for Monday with CNO/CFO. The recruiter then called back and said they had decided not to hire for the position until after the new year. I got a text from my referral today saying the hospital had called and talked to her yesterday. Can a recruiter release your referral info to the client without your permission? The recruiter states he does not give this info to the client but he was the only one who had the names and numbers.

Comment: Legally? Probably, unless they signed something that prevents them from sharing this information. Ethically? Maybe, but does it matter? They did it either way. Future recruiters may or may not do it. Don't give them that information if you don't want them to share it, or at least explicitly ask them to not share it with any given company without your explicit permission.

Comment: You know they could have have just been calling the businesses you worked at and asking about you.  That information they can get from your resume and google.

Comment: I had a situation where a recruiter called me since I was a referral on someone's resume. They simply asked me if I worked with X, and whether I would give a good reference. I said yes, and the call ended. Never heard from them again either the recruiter or the place of employment. Either way you should always notify your references that you put them on the list and whether they will give you a good reference. Don't just put random names without talking to them first.

Comment: Unless you had an NDA or agreement in place saying to the otherwise, a recruiter can and often does do anything they like with your info. Maybe the recruiter was telling the truth, maybe they were hiring in the new year after all and you were a contender. Perhaps in the meantime they were simply doing their dew diligence and contacting your references.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind recruiters make their money when employers hire. They're not actually working in your favor. So the way they work is they gather up the best possible candidates, help polish up the resume, then present them to the employer. The employer then interviews whoever they like, then if they're hired, the recruiter gets a share of the salary.

With that said, yes, it's possible the recruiter submitted your resume with your referrals. Unless you signed something to say they are working for you, they are actually working in the interest of the employer.

A lesson for the future though. Hopefully you are in good contact with your referrals. If you are seeking employment and you haven't notified your employer and some of those are on that referral, I would quickly talk to them. In the future, don't include referrals to the recruiter and instead print "referrals on request." Chances are your resume and referrals are now sold to the recruiter network and you'll soon get calls about your position at random far away places.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that he has released it to them, but told you he didn't.

Also, perhaps you have it in your resume or mentioned it during your interview.

If you have "References available upon request" clause in your resume, and gave it to recruiter, he can give it out, unless you specifically told him not to without your approval.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a recruiter release your referral info to the client without your permission?

This may depend on jurisdiction, but in all likelihood **yes** - unless you've a specific contract with them that says they *won't* share this info.